# In ReactiveCocoa, is there any convention for subscribeNext and subscribeCompleted?

Tags: objective-c, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

As title, is there any convention for `subscribeNext` and `subscribeCompleted` in ReactiveCocoa?

I know that `subscribeNext` allows you to pass one object but not in `subscribeCompleted`. But I would like to know more about semantic differences.

For example, if I implement a timer `RACSignal`, what method should I use (`sendNext` or `sendCompleted`)? Or should I call both of them?

Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The semantics of a signal are that it can send as many values as it wants, but once it completes or errors, no more values are sent.

So if the timer repeats, you want to use `-sendNext:`. If it never repeats, `-sendCompleted` would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! So does it mean that I can `-sendCompleted` for multiple times (syntactically) but semantically inappropriate?

Comment: You can `-sendCompleted` multiple times, but only the first one would ever be received. After a subscriber has been sent completed or error, it tears itself down. It won't receive any events after that point.